# OS Halting on Compare Strings

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, virtualbox, osdev

I'm attempting to create an Operating System, I don't know every in and out of assembly language, I am mainly learning as I go. Here is the problem, I built a simple function to compare two strings (`eax` and `ebx`) the problem is that when I run the code to do this my system doesn't execute anything after the call... What did I do wrong?

```
compare:
    xor ecx, ecx
    .by_char:
        mov dh, [eax+ecx]
        mov dl, [ebx+ecx]
        cmp dh, dl
        inc ecx
        je .zero_test
        stc
        jmp .done
    .zero_test:
        cmp dh, 0
        je .done
        jmp .by_char
    .done:
        ret
```

For reference here is the code I am calling this function from:

```
start:
    mov esp, stack
    mov si, msg_welcome
    call print

    mov eax, msg_welcome
    mov ebx, msg_diskerr
    call compare

    jc j_aa
    jmp j_bb 

    j_aa:
        mov si, msg_strnequ
        jmp part_b

    j_bb:
        mov si, msg_strrequ

    part_b:
        call print

        mov eax, msg_booting
        mov ebx, msg_booting
        call compare

        jc j_cc
        jmp j_dd

        j_cc:
            mov si, msg_strnequ
            jmp part_c

        j_dd:
            mov si, msg_strrequ

    part_c:
        call print
        jmp halt

halt:
    hlt
    jmp halt
```

Here is where I am defining my variables:

```
bss:
    msg_welcome: db "Welcome To Hypr Byte!", 10, 13, 10, 13, 0
    msg_nokernl: db "FATAL: Missing or Corrupted Kernel. System Halted...", 10, 13, 10, 13, 0
    msg_diskerr db "FATAL: An error occured while attempting to read the disk. Please go to https://www.instinct-loop.xyz/hypr/help to recieve support...", 0
    msg_bterror db "Uh oh! An error occured while attempting to boot. Please go to https://www.instinct-loop.xyz/hypr/help to recieve support...", 0
    msg_booting db "Attempting to load the kernel...", 10, 13, 10, 13, 0
    msg_kreturn db "Oops! The kernel ran into a fatal error... System Halted!", 0

    msg_strnequ db "Strings are Not Equal!", 10, 13, 0
    msg_strrequ db "Strings are Equal!", 10, 13, 0
```

Comment: Is your O/S 16 or 32 bits? - because this `mov si, msg_welcome` loads a 16-bit pointer whereas this `mov eax, msg_welcome` loads a 32-bit one.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I believe you might be onto something, my OS is 16 bit, but when I try to use 16 bit registers in my compare function it tells me that I am giving it an invalid effective address.

Comment: Doing `je .zero_test` after `inc ecx` is not a good idea since it modifies flags. You are testing `ecx==0` with that. Shouldn't cause your problem directly though. PS: learn to use a debugger before trying to write an OS.

Comment: @Jester thanks for both the tip and the info, Will look into getting a debugger and I moved the increment statement, however when I ran the OS it crashed VirtualBox.

Comment: Unrelated: your `bss:` label makes no sense.  The BSS is for zero-initialized arrays / variables like `char buf[1024];`, not data or read-only data.  (Or if you don't zero it, the BSS is for uninitialized storage.)

Comment: @WolfHybrid23: 16-bit addressing modes can only use `[bx|bp + si|di]` or a subset of that.  Using 32-bit addressing modes is a valid workaround if you can't just pass pointers in `si` and `di` for addr modes like `[si]` and `[di]` like a normal person.  But only if you zero-extend the 16-bit addresses into the full 32-bit register, otherwise high garbage can lead to a segment limit violation.  (In real mode, segments implicitly have a 64k limit; offset > 65535 will fault.)

Comment: @PeterCordes like I said in the post, I don't know all of the ins and outs of assembly, thanks for letting me know so I can fix that.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to crash virtualbox itself. Anyway, this isn't a **complete** example, we can not test it. For example, we don't know where `stack` is and whether you have set up the segment registers correctly.

Comment: @Jester when I say it crashed virtual box I mean that virtual box alerted me that it ran into an error while emulating the system and had to exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my OS is 16 bit, but when I try to use 16 bit registers in my compare function it tells me that I am giving it an invalid effective address.

16-bit addressing modes can only use `[bx|bp + si|di + constant]` or a subset of that.  Using 32-bit addressing modes is a valid workaround if you can't just pass pointers in `si` and `di` for addr modes like `[si]` and `[di]` like a normal person.

**But only if you zero-extend the 16-bit addresses into the full 32-bit register**, otherwise high garbage can lead to a segment limit violation.  In real mode, segments implicitly have a 64k limit; offset > 65535 will fault.

You're probably not actually crashing VirtualBox itself, but you could be crashing the virtual guest machine with a triple fault or something.

`mov eax, msg_welcome` does write the full register with the zero-extended address, unlike `mov si, msg_welcome`

---

Your loop will always exit after the first iteration, because `inc ecx` / `je .zero_test` falls through.  INC clears ZF because incrementing ECX from 0 to 1 leaves ECX != 0.

Presumably you should `inc` before `cmp`/`je` if you want `je` to read flags set by `cmp`.

I'm not sure where your code would actually fault.  Use a debugger to find out, e.g. by running it inside BOCHS instead of VirtualBox.  BOCHS has a debugger built-in which understands segmentation, unlike attaching GDB to qemu or virtualbox as a GDB-remote.

---

Your loop is pretty inefficient, BTW.  You can use `cmp dl, [di]` or something and put a `jne` at the bottom.  If you break out of the loop with a cmp/jcc, you can put a `test dl,dl`/`jnz` as the loop branch at the bottom.

You should never write a `jcc` over a `jmp`, just write a JCC with the opposite condition that falls through.  And here you can fall through to a RET instead of a `jmp .done`.  (The one exception is if you have to jump farther than -128..+127 bytes, and you're targeting an ancient CPU that doesn't support JCC rel16, only short JCC rel8.)

On an AMD CPU (no partial-register renaming), `mov dh, [mem]` has a false dependency on `mov dl, [mem]`, so there's extra latency for merging the load values before your `cmp` can run.  That's another reason for using a cmp-with-mem instead of 2 loads.

Comment: I figured this out based on what you and others told me, thanks!

Comment: The loop should exit immediately because the `je` will not jump and then the code just does `stc; jmp .done; ret`

Comment: @Jester: Oh right, then IDK what's going on.  I only looked as far as JCC over a JMP (/facepalm) and wasn't interested in untangling that crap; I was thinking the JMP was back to the top of the inner loop.